# How to do animation of CSS for N seconds, then proceed to route?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a login.html that will redirect to an index.html upon right credentials. The post and authentication works on the backend, so no worries there.

The problem now is that upon submit, the browser will simply open the ?  `static/jquery.min.js` - This makes sense, as my `login.js` look like here(fetched from an example):

```
$('.login-input').on('focus', function() {
  $('.login').addClass('focused');
});

$('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.login').removeClass('focused').addClass('loading');
});
```

The `e.preventDefault();` I'm assuming overrides my post seen in the below code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='static/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/login.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="static/images/favicon.png"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Super title!</title>

    <style>
        <A bunch of css goes here>
    </style>



</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <header class="login-header"><span class="text">LOGIN</span><span class="loader"></span></header>
    <form class="login-form" action="/loginp" method="post">
        <label><input class="login-input" type="text" name="username"/></label>
        <label><input class="login-input" type="password" name="password"/></label>
        <button class="login-btn" type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: How do I alter this login.js jQuery file to not override the /loginp post action, but rather upon this action, animate for 2 seconds, and then stop?

Running just the example locally does work with the animation, but of course it goes into an endless loop which I don't want for a real application, obviously :)

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing. Why do you need e.PreventDefault() when you just change a css property? You need to use it to post the form via ajax instead of the normal behaviour about submitting

Comment: Why do you want to delay the submittal? Doesn't seem convenient for user

Comment: @charlietfl i guess he wants to show an animation on the form on submitting and do the submit only after displaying the animation. Easy to do with ajax no?

Comment: @charlietfl I want to do something like this jsfiddle, where it after 1.5 seconds or such, loads the page it's supposed to and will right now(without the jquery code) https://jsfiddle.net/cbll11/17v6mawx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout(function(){ //redirection code }, 3000);` to redirect after 3 seconds. Use any other number of miliseconds that fits your needs.

**UPDATE**

This is the working example based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfa2qsh3/

And the code is

```
$('.login-input').on('focus', function() {
  $('.login').addClass('focused');
});

function doOnSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.login').removeClass('focused').addClass('loading');
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('.login-form').submit()
   },3000); // here you set this function to be executed after 3 seconds.
   $('.login').unbind("submit", doOnSubmit); 
   // this gets executed inmediatly and unbinds the actual behaviour, 
   //as you're going to redirect the user to another page it should be no problem
}
$('.login').on('submit', doOnSubmit);
```

Comment: But the preventDefault will override the routing as of now - how would I change the login.js to fit that, then? Do I need to manually put in the routing to the jQuery code? :)

Comment: I've edited as such: `<form class="login-form" action="/loginp" method="post" id="loginform">` and added "#loginform" where you have "#formID", but it again opens just the jquery.min.js file when you press enter - on submit(clicking), it does load the next page but there is no animation.

Comment: @cbll Updated again, please try now

Comment: I tried your new code. Unfortunately it's the same behaviour. Filling the form and pressing "Enter" = it opens the login.js. Pressing the button loads the next page as it would've otherwise.

Comment: @cbll https://jsfiddle.net/nfa2qsh3/ please try with it. I did an update with a non working answer, my mistake. If you want to change the actual page of the redirection, please modify `action` atribute of your `form` element.I tested it with click on the play and with enter, and it does animate and redirect after 3 seconds.

Comment: Still no dice. Now it redirects again to the jquery.min.js and says `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.`

Comment: Ok, so your actual implementation is not working as you would like, but that is a different issue. The problem that you've exposed in the Question, is solved by the code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nfa2qsh3/

Comment: Sorry I pathed my jquery.min.js file wrong. I have it right now, however, the behaviour is as before - no animation, it just loads the next page.

Comment: @cbll In the fiddle? or in your non-disclosed code. The problem is not the answer is not working. Is that you're failing to adapt the provided solution to your code, and that's a different issue. I have to insist, the fiddle is working as expected, it displays the animation and after 3 seconds redirect to the path provided in the `action` attribute of your `form` so if you have a different question please post a new one, and accept this one for your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? On the first submit (manual by user) it shows only the animation (putting variable to true), so when the code triggers it again, animation is true so it execute the route.

```
var animationStarted = false;
$('.login').on('submit', function(e) {
  if (!animationStarted) {
    e.preventDefault();
    animationStarted = true;
    $('.login').removeClass('focused').addClass('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.login').submit();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Comment: you should not be using global variables like that, by no means you should modify global variable state on functions that don't get the variable passed as parameter and, instead, access them through scope.

Comment: JSfiddle here... Do the input and it gives the animation :) https://jsfiddle.net/cbll11/17v6mawx/